# Hauppauge Capture Card via LAN

Tags: lan, tuner-card

My desktop in my office has a Hauppauge WinTV Capture Card.

Is it possible to view Broadcast TV on my laptop in the living-room?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, I've done it with MythTV.  Wireless streaming live TV from one side of the house to the other.  Of course this invovles installing Linux on the computer with the TV card, but you can dual boot Linux/Windows if you so desire.

Mythbuntu would probably by your distribution of choice.